# keycloak.json file in springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, keycloak

Is it necessary to have a keycloak.json file even if we have configured everything in application.properties for a spring boot application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming yours spring-boot application , if you are using `keycloak-spring-boot-starter` spring-boot adapter, Then you have all your configurations in application.properties.

You can find examples here https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/app-springboot

Comment: It helped.We doesn't need to have keycloak.json file.

Answer (score 27):

If you are using Spring Security Adapter, add bean **KeycloakConfigResolver** in your configuration file. It will use application.properties instead of WEB-INF/keycloack.json

```
@Bean
   public KeycloakConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
      return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
   }
```

See: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/05/25/easily-secure-your-spring-boot-applications-with-keycloak/  **Creating a SecurityConfig class** section

Comment: Works for KC V3.3.0.Final :)